# Counting vowels in all european languages

Tags: c#

How can I count all vowels in the text in different languages? (For example: Germany has specific vowels with dots) And how can I do it in C#?

Comment: I don't think there's a function that returns the vowels for a particular language. You'd have to define that yourself.

Comment: I need all european languages(

Comment: First of all, you should be clear about, what you mean by "european language". Keep in mind there is also the greek alphabet and the cyrillic alphabet  used in some european countries.

Comment: You can either recognise all of the characters with diacritics too, or you there are a few ways you can strip diacritics off characters to count them. e.g. there are Unicode ways of splitting a u with umlaut into an umlaut combining character and a u, then you can just count the u, or there are some good diacritic-stripping functions out there e.g. based on the code in Apache Lucene.

Comment: I also need Cyrillic and Greek and Checz etc.

Comment: Your best bet then is to look through the Unicode code tables and work out which characters you consider vowels, and then count those. I'm not aware of any 'IsVowel' function you can just use. but I could believe it's out there somewhere.

Comment: Vowel-ness is context sensitive. The "y" in "yellow" is not a vowel, but the "y" in "fly" is. Even "w" can be a vowel (in the word "crwth"). Vowel-ness is quite a complicated linguistic concept that cannot be reduced to "whenever I see this character, it is a vowel."

Comment: Out of curiosity: What do you intend to do with that information?

Comment: @RaymondChen oh, I am Russian, there are vowels in alphabet and this letters are vowels in any case and in any place in word

Comment: @PMF just a study task)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found solution. I wanted to get list of all possible vowels, but here is replacing the diacritic letters by usual and then counting vowels:

```
private int VowelCounter()
    {
        int Counter = 0;
        foreach (var word in text)
        {
            string WordWithoutDiactrics = RemoveDiacritics(word.ToLower());

           
            foreach (var letter in WordWithoutDiactrics)
            {
                if (Vowels.Contains(letter))
                {
                    Counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return Counter;
    }

    private readonly static Regex nonSpacingMarkRegex =
        new Regex(@"\p{Mn}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static string RemoveDiacritics(string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var normalizedText =
            text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);

        return nonSpacingMarkRegex.Replace(normalizedText, string.Empty);
    }
```